# Inherit parameters from init method in Class Python

Tags: python

I a beginer in Python and I am trying to understand classes.
In this case, I do not know why I cannot take the parameter "weight" from my init method?

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, weight):
    
        self.weight=weight

    def go_in(self, age,height):
       
        enter_to_disco= age*height*self.weight
        if enter_to_disco<10:
            print('enter to disco')
        else:
            print(f'do not enter to disco')
    

peter=Person.go_in(13,20,1)
```

it raises:

```
      7     def go_in(self, age,height):
      8 
----> 9         enter_to_disco= age*height*self.weight
     10         if enter_to_disco<10:
     11             print('enter to disco')

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'weight'
```

Comment: You never create an instance of `Person`, and so `Person.__init__` is never called.

Comment: Something like `Person(80).go_in(25, 190)` would be closer to what you want, if the person weights 80kg, is 25 years old, and 190cm tall.

Comment: @chepner yes as the weight should be in the constructor. I did not notice that the method `go_in` only takes two arguments. I removed my previous comment. `Person(80).go_in(25, 190)` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create your object then call the method:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, weight):
    
        self.weight=weight

    def go_in(self, age,height):
       
        enter_to_disco= age*height*self.weight
        if enter_to_disco<10:
            print('enter to disco')
        else:
            print(f'do not enter to disco')
    

  Person(90).go_in(20,1)
```

Comment: Since the `go_in` method doesn't return anything, it might be more useful to have the final line be turned into two lines: `peter = Person(90)`, and `peter.go_in(20, 1)`.